# evp_encrypt wont work in a for loop in c

Tags: c, encryption, for-loop

I'm new here so please excuse if I'm doing something wrong.

I attempt to make an array with encrypted strings, I'm using the EVP API for the encryption. This works fine, but wHen I try to use the encrypt function in a foor loop the console gives me nothing.

Here is my encrypt function:

```
char *encrypt(char *key, char *iv, char * source){

    //char *target;
    int in_len, out_len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    in_len=strlen((const char *)source);
    unsigned char *target = (unsigned char *) malloc(in_len);
        //printf("This is the text before ciphering: %s\n",source);
        //printf("The length of the string is: %d\n",in_len);
        //starting the encryption process
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
        EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&ctx,EVP_aes_128_cbc(),NULL,(unsigned char*) key,(unsigned char*)iv);
        EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx,target,&out_len,(unsigned char*)source,in_len);
        EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&ctx,target,&out_len);
        target[out_len] = '\0';

        //EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);


        return ((char *)target);
}
```

and in main the loop:

```
int main(){
    char source[17]="Shahababamamaaaa";
    char key[17]="ahardtobreakkey1";
    char iv[17] = "veryinterestingv";
     int rows = 1280;
     int cols = (3*800)/16;
        char *encrypted=encrypt(key, iv, source);
        printf("encrypted: %s\n", encrypted);
        char *encrypted2;
        encrypted2=encrypt(key, iv, encrypted);
        printf("encrypted2: %s\n", encrypted2);
        char *mx[rows];
        char *in, *temp;
        in = (char *) malloc ( cols * sizeof(char) );
        temp =(char *) malloc ( strlen(encrypted) );
        int i, j;

        for (i=0; i<5; i++){
            strcpy(in,encrypted);
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                    printf("in: %s\n", in);
                    strcpy(temp, encrypted2);
                    printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
                    memset(encrypted2,0x00, strlen(encrypted));
                    encrypted2=encrypt(key, iv,temp);
                    printf("encrypted2 nach j=%d : %s\n",j, encrypted2);

                    mx[i]=in;
            }

        }
        printf("Stele 0 Inhalt %s\n",mx[0]);
        printf("Laenge von 1 %d\n", strlen(mx[0]));

        //system ("PAUSE");
        free(in);
        return 0;

     }
```

What am I missing? Is it imposible to use encrypt2 again?
Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you expect to have? you assigned mx[i] with in 15 times while in come from encrypted only , which is not related with encrypt2 in the for loop.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I want to use encrypt2 again. I tried to put it also in mx[i], but that didn't work. As I was looking for what could be wrong, a thought of printing encrypt2 and even that doesn't work. As I wrote I'm not getting anithing in the console is empty. When I comment this line out:encrypted2=encrypt(key, iv,temp); it works. That is what is I don't understand.

Comment: Hello everyone, I now saw that the error must be in my ecrypt function. If I use it more then 5 times it crasches. Can somebody look at it and tell me what is not correct? I simply can't see the misstake. Thanx alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, the main problem is in your encrypt() function, but also how you call it.  You are using malloc() to allocate memory inside your function, and never freeing it, which is a memory leak (and malloc is a no-no in c++ anyway).  You are also not running the cleanup function for your ctx.  And your encrypt_final is overwriting the first part of your output buffer.  So, here's a cleaned up encrypt(), and a matching decrypt():

```
int encrypt(unsigned char *key, 
        unsigned char *iv, 
        unsigned char * source, 
        unsigned char* target, 
        int in_len) // Need an in length.  Not all input is going to be
                    // zero-terminated, for example if we're reading from a file

{

    int out_len; // Return the output length.  Because it also won't be null
                 // terminated, and may contain null characters inline

    int final_out_len; // So that we don't overwrite out_len with the final call
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&ctx,EVP_aes_128_cbc(),NULL,key,iv);
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx,target,&out_len,source,in_len);
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&ctx,target+out_len,&final_out_len);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    return out_len+final_out_len; // need to sum these together, because both
                                  // encrypt calls wrote data
}
```

And to decrypt:

```
int decrypt(unsigned char *key, 
        unsigned char *iv, 
        unsigned char * source, 
        unsigned char* target, 
        int in_len)
{

    int out_len=0,final_out_len=0;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(&ctx,EVP_aes_128_cbc(),NULL,key,iv);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx,target,&out_len,source,in_len);
    EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&ctx,target+out_len,&final_out_len);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    //Just to be nice, we'll add a zero at the end of the decrypted string
    target[out_len+final_out_len] = 0;
    return out_len+final_out_len;
}
```

Pulling it all together (in a loop, to prove your concept):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned char key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    unsigned char ivec[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    char *raw_buffer = "This is a test string";
    int raw_count = strlen(raw_buffer);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        unsigned char *decrypted_buffer = new unsigned char[raw_count+64];
        unsigned char *encrypted_buffer = new unsigned char[raw_count+64];
        int final_len = encrypt(key,ivec,(unsigned char*)raw_buffer,(unsigned char*)encrypted_buffer,raw_count);
        int dec_len = decrypt(key,ivec,(unsigned char*)encrypted_buffer,(unsigned char*)decrypted_buffer,final_len);
        printf("raw_count: %i\nfinal_len: %i\ndec_len: %i\n",raw_count,final_len,dec_len);
        printf("Original str: \n%s\n",raw_buffer);
        printf("Encrypted: \n%s\n", encrypted_buffer);
        printf("Decrypted:\n%s\n\n\n", decrypted_buffer);
        delete[] decrypted_buffer;
        delete[] encrypted_buffer;
    }
    char c;
    c=getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me alot. But there is still something I don't understand and I will be very greatefull if you can explain that to me. Why do we get a length of 32 after encryption, when we encrypt a string of lenght of say 16? I thought that aes 128 works with blocksize=16 Byte. And one more question why do we have to make the size of encrypted buffer =[raw_count+64]? How do you know that it should be 64 Byte longer than the lenght of what we want to encrypt. Sorry if these questions are too silly, but I realy want to understand this. A huge thank you again.

Comment: From the documentation [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html):

> EVP_EncryptUpdate() encrypts inl bytes from the buffer in and writes the encrypted version to out. This function can be called multiple times to encrypt successive blocks of data. The amount of data written depends on the block alignment of the encrypted data: as a result the amount of data written may be anything from zero bytes to (inl + cipher_block_size - 1) so outl should contain sufficient room. The actual number of bytes written is placed in outl.