# Using AES CBC from OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I am writing C++ server function which will be called a java process by passing a encrypted string with AES CBC 128 bit. I can't change the singature of this C++ function.

For this I am using openssl AES_set_decrypt_key() and AES_cbc_encrypt() methods in C++ code.
But in the signature of AES_cbc_encrypt() there is a length parameter and I believe that it is the length of the actual string(unencrypted). However, my C++ code doesn't know the actual length. Am I making a wrong approach? Can anybody help please?

The sample code is as given:

```
unsigned char* decrypt(unsigned char* l_cInput_ptr)
{
unsigned char key[] = "asdfghjklpoiuytr";
unsigned char iv[] = "asdfghjklpoiuytr";

unsigned char * dec_out = (unsigned char *)malloc(80*sizeof(char));
memset(dec_out, 0, 80);

AES_KEY dec_key;

AES_set_decrypt_key(key,128,&dec_key);
AES_cbc_encrypt(l_cInput_ptr, dec_out, 16, &dec_key, iv, AES_DECRYPT);

....
}
```

l_cInput_ptr is encrypted string. The length of actual string is not known to decrypt() method. I have just used a dummy value of 16 in this case. And I can't change the java code.

Comment: [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) and [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption). If you are not sure, use authenticated encryption.

Comment: possible duplicate of [evp\_encrypt wont work in a for loop in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329842/evp-encrypt-wont-work-in-a-for-loop-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

`AES_cbc_encrypt()` length parameter is the length of the input. So for decryption, this is the length of the *encrypted* data, which, for AES in CBC mode, will always be a multiple of 16 bytes (by the way, it's not clear from your code how you're going to get length of supplied data pointed by `unsigned char*`).

Decrypted data will be of the same length and will be *padded* (usually PKCS# 7 padding, sometimes just adding NULLs, but may be anything, really). You will have to remove this padding after decryption to get original plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Andrey is right, I meet the same problem. if the raw unencrypted text length is not multiple of 16 bytes, the decrypted data is as the same lehgth of the raw data without padding. if the raw unencrypted text length is multiple of 16 bytes(n), the decrypted length is n + 1 with 16 bytes padding, we need to remove it. here is the code :

```
AES_cbc_encrypt(&encrypted, &decrypted, length, &key2, iv2, 0);

length = strlen(decrypted);
if (length > AES_BLOCK_SIZE && (length % AES_BLOCK_SIZE == 0))
{
    length = length - AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    memset(decrypted + length, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
}
printf("xxx %s", decrypted);
```